7x10 floor and a 8x8 and a 6x1 carpet, only one cut allowed
We have a 8x8 carpet, we can do only one cut of any complexity and also we have an uncuttable 6x1 carpet. We need to fill a 7x10 space using those 2. The 8x8 can only be cut into two pieces.
We have tried all the simpler shapes like an L and varying stair shapes, we cannot find the solution. We only got the hint that a normal person wouldn't cut their carpet like that. Diagonal cuts are allowed.
The question comes from my father but no one in our family can find the solution. He said we could use any tools, he himself once solved it when he was in uni decades ago when asked by a friend.

Here is one way it can be done.

 

Path of discovery:

 Assuming there is a simple, symmetrical solution on grid squares with the 6x1 piece in the center, the outer ring is forced.



 The bold portions of the border in the 8x8 piece appear in two places on the 7x10 piece. After another step in this direction, the solution is complete.



Can you please explain it more?

@EtackSxchange I'm not sure what there is to explain. You cut the 8x8 rug as shown in the left image, then rearrange it together with the 6x1 rug to form the 7x10 rug as shown in the right image.

That was fast. Any insight in how you solved it? Or have you just solved many puzzles like this before?

@Oliphaunt Assume a simple, symmetrical solution exists. With the 6x1 placed as shown, the border of the 8x8 is forced and the full solution follows.

Since this is brilliant but non-intuitive, most of us could do with a clearer explanation of how you stepwise reason towards the solution. Something like: a) in the solution the 6x1 cannot go along an outside edge without leaving a 1x1 hole, which would make the cut of the 8x8 asymmetric, which cannot be. Therefore, the 6x1 must be placed such that it fits an internal hole in the reassembled cut 8x8. I think symmetry implies that must be at the center, i.e. column 4 b) The 8x8 must be cut in two symmetric pieces with width 7, so how do we slice a column away?

c) First we try and reject rectangles. Then we try and reject a staircase with a 1x1 slope. Then we try a staircase with a 1x2 slope.

@smci See edit. Note that I started with an assumption (hypothesis), and found it to be true.

Awesome, thanks. I think once you start a 1x2 staircase, you're forced to continue it.

One way to think about it is that the 8x8 piece needs to become two longer and one narrower, meaning the first "path of discovery" step above is locked as long as there are no diagonal cuts. I wonder if there's a simple way to rule those out?

This is awesome!

For anyone wanting to play around with this themselves, here is a Desmos graph (without answer spoilers) that allows you to explore different shapes. It makes the mild assumption that:

 the 8x8 carpet is cut symmetrically.

Here is the graph with the solution. Using this you can more clearly see the reasoning discussed in the comments of Daniel's answer, and also the path towards how you would discover this.

 One of the shapes must include a corner, and WLOG we start from (0, 0). The first adjustable point has to lie on the y-axis as otherwise nothing would be able to fill the void in the left side of the 10x7 rectangle. It cannot have a y coordinate less than 1 as otherwise at least one of the shapes would need to have a height greater than 7 and not fit in the 10x7. The second point must have an x coordinate of exactly 2 as otherwise the combined shapes would not have a total length of 10. It is easy to see how the rest of the construction is forced from this point as others have already pointed out.

Picture of the answer:

 

